# Excel Search then find Median with Filters

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, median

I've spent the better half of a day attempting to resolve a formula/VBA code to sort through some data in excel - I appreciate any and all input!

#### Example Image

[image: Example Image]

As you may see, in this small sample (my actual sample is ~4000 rows), on Worksheet 1, I have three columns of data. The first two are identifiers and the last is a date.

In the most simple terms, what I would like to do is search Column A for a value, say 7, then pull the date from Column C. The result of a search for 7 should be two different dates, I would then like to determine the median (I know that a median between two numbers is a strange thing to look for, remember this is just an example).

Diving a bit further in, the value that I'm searching for is determined from a separate set of data on Worksheet 2. Right now, I'm using the VLOOKUP function and obtaining one result per "Definition," which does not allow me to perform the median calculation.

Considering there should be numerous results from one search, I would also like to be able to include some filters/logic. For example, "if Column A includes a positive search result, do not also include the date as a result (for later performing the calculation) from this row in Column B." Also, if an identifier is slightly different, such as 16.5, 17.5, and 18.5, it would be great to be able to handle that somehow.

Please let me know whether my problem statement is clear and I appreciate any and all responses pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried? And given your points about the complex filtering and fuzzy matching, I'd say it'll need a VBA solution.

Comment: median of number in column A or median of date in column C ???